How to create a datetimeindex from integer date and time columns in Pandas
I have a dataframe with columns corresponding to days since 1/1/1900 (date) and seconds as part of a 24h day (time).
    date    time
0   40603   34222
1   40603   34223
2   40603   34224
3   40603   34225
4   40603   34226
5   40603   34227
6   40603   34228
7   40603   34229

What's the easiest way to create a more standard datetimeindex from this for using to create an index for the dataframe (with endgoal being to use the index to resample the dataframe).
Desired output would look something like this:
    date    time    idx
0   40603   34222   2011-03-03 09:30:02
1   40603   34223   2011-03-03 09:30:03
2   40603   34224   2011-03-03 09:30:04
3   40603   34225   2011-03-03 09:30:05
4   40603   34226   2011-03-03 09:30:06
5   40603   34227   2011-03-03 09:30:07
6   40603   34228   2011-03-03 09:30:08
7   40603   34229   2011-03-03 09:30:09

Have tried versions of adding days since 1900 via timedelta but it feels way more complicated than it should be given my inputs (although maybe that's just working with dates in Python in general).
Most recent attempt:
df['ref_date'] = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(df.date) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=df.time)

Returns TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series

Show your code please. Cause if it's already as simple as it gets, there's your answer.

Adding days since 1900 via timedelta is exactly how I would do it.

@MarkRansom @wjandrea, for instance, this threw an error:  df['ref_date'] =  datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(df.date) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=df.time) / TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series

You can use Timestamp and to_timedelta which work with Series:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[40603] * 8, 'time':range(34222, 34230)})
df['idx'] = pd.Timestamp(1900, 1, 1) + pd.to_timedelta(df.date, unit='d') + pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='s')
print(df)

Output:
    date   time                 idx
0  40603  34222 2011-03-03 09:30:22
1  40603  34223 2011-03-03 09:30:23
2  40603  34224 2011-03-03 09:30:24
3  40603  34225 2011-03-03 09:30:25
4  40603  34226 2011-03-03 09:30:26
5  40603  34227 2011-03-03 09:30:27
6  40603  34228 2011-03-03 09:30:28
7  40603  34229 2011-03-03 09:30:29


Python's datetime library isn't built to work with Pandas objects.* You should use the Pandas tools instead, namely Timestamp and to_timedelta. For example:
import pandas as pd

base_date = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')
date_delta = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'], unit='days')
time_delta = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='seconds')

print(base_date + date_delta + time_delta)

0   2011-03-03 09:30:22
1   2011-03-03 09:30:23
2   2011-03-03 09:30:24
3   2011-03-03 09:30:25
4   2011-03-03 09:30:26
5   2011-03-03 09:30:27
6   2011-03-03 09:30:28
7   2011-03-03 09:30:29
dtype: datetime64[ns]


More info in the Pandas user guide:

10 minutes to pandas § Time series
Time series / date functionality
Time deltas

* More generally, tools built on top of NumPy, including Pandas as well as SciPy, aren't served well by the Python standard library, but they provide their own tools plus they're compatible amongst each other.
